# android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" is not working in android

Tags: android, layout

I am using this layout to make image and text in center.but its not working .i am simply using  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true".why its not working i dont understand. can someone please help to solve this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image_tutorial1" />

        <TextView
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/info4"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

In the layout, `RelativeLayout`'s width is set to `wrap-content`, its not taking the entire available width at all. It's contents *are* being centered but their parent `View` is shrinking to fit around them.

try `fill_parent` for root:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Also, a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"` and `gravity="center_horizontal"` will do the same, more easily.

Answer (score 4):

With RelativeLayout use:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

with

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

use [android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"] under RelativeLayout layout, then it will work

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: i m using relative layout but it is not working.i also tried linearlayout but that is also not working

Comment: it only works under relative layout then it works, i use this many times

Comment: did u try the main layout will linearlayout and textview will in relative layout

Comment: can u check where i m mistaken?

Comment: if i set marginleft for textview then both image and textview comes in center .thats i dont want to use

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25014/discussion-between-rohit-and-ankita-gahoi)

Comment: android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"

Comment: i dont want to set margin left .it dont work for all devices.i want to make it only in center

Comment: now we r going from office , sorry  see u on monday at 9.30 am , nice weekend

Comment: this is the best solution 
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

Answer (score 0):

you using this wrong for your RelativeLayout

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

it should be

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```